# Why is the output of predict a factor with 0 levels?

Tags: r, naivebayes

I generated a naive Bayes classifier using `e1071` and then ran the following

```r
test <- as.data.frame(readRDS('ContactsComplaints2014.rds'))
load(file='data2015.nb.RData')
prediction <- predict(data2015.nb,subset(test[1:3000,], select=-c(didComplain)))
```

In the terminal I entered

`> prediction`

and got

```r
factor(0)
Levels:
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to label the names of the classes you want to classify as `as.factor()`. Then it will work.

Comment: Why do we need to do this?